# jq: avoid nested array mapping

Tags: jq

Here's my document:

```json
{
  "_id": "a6c8004c-efdc-4462-b474-31df2d417be3",
  "address": [
    {
      "city": {
        "value": "2505300"
      },
      "state": {
        "value": "25"
      },
      "postalCode": {
        "value": "25132"
      }
    }
  ]
}
{
  "_id": "aa4b4ba9-32e3-4384-8cd8-0852bae0029b",
  "address": [
    {
      "city": {
        "value": "2521700"
      },
      "state": {
        "value": "25"
      },
      "postalCode": {
        "value": "25300"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Currently, I'm applying this JQ filter:

```
def pick_address:
    {
        city: .city | .value,
        postalCode: .postalCode | .value,
        state: .state | .value
    };

map(.address | map(pick_address))
```

---

I'm getting this:

```json
[
  [
    {
      "city": "2505300",
      "postalCode": "25132",
      "state": "25"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "city": "2521700",
      "postalCode": "25300",
      "state": "25"
    }
  ]
]
```

---

As you can see, I'm getting above objects with nested array.

I need to get it as:

```json
[
  {
    "city": "2505300",
    "postalCode": "25132",
    "state": "25"
  },
  {
    "city": "2521700",
    "postalCode": "25300",
    "state": "25"
  }
]
```

---

I don't quite figure out what's wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mapping `pick_address` onto the `address` array

```
map(.address | map(pick_address))
```

just apply it directly onto its elements:

```
map(.address[] | pick_address)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/f-WWqJ--ZD)

On a side note: If within `pick_address` the operation `.value` is being applied to *all* fields, then `def pick_address: map_values(.value);` would be equivalent. [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1iuHhhuqYR)

Answer (score 1):

More dynamic solution without any hardcoded keys, using

- [`with_entries()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example27)
- [`--slurp`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)

```
jq --slurp 'map(.address[] | with_entries(.value |= .value))'
```

---

Will produce

```json
[
  {
    "city": "2505300",
    "state": "25",
    "postalCode": "25132"
  },
  {
    "city": "2521700",
    "state": "25",
    "postalCode": "25300"
  }
]
```

As you can test in this [online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/jNbRsuipPA)

Comment: mmm... I think it's not exactly I need. You are getting `[{...}],[{...}]` instead of `[{...},{...}]`.

Comment: You are right @Jordi, too fast! I've changed my answer to the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it simpler to just do this?

```
jq '.[].address[] | [{city: .city.value, state: .state.value, postalCode: .postalCode.value}]'
```